# UINavigationBar change colors on push

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using 2 different bar tint colors at `UINavigationBar` in different views. I'n changing color with that method in both views:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = COLOR
}
```

When I tap on back button color is not changed smoothly (you can see blink on last second).

[image: Visual bug]

But everything is okay if just swipe view back instead of tapping on back button.

[image: No visual bug]

How to make smooth transition in both situations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've coded final solution that looks most comfortable to use (don't need to use a lot of overrides in own view controllers). It works perfectly at iOS 10 and easy adoptable for own purposes.

#### GitHub

You can check [**GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/Sorix/1d8543b18cfd76c12c36525bc280a35d) for full class code and more detailed guide, I won't post full code here because Stackoverflow is not intended for storing a lot of code.

#### Usage

Download Swift file for GitHub. To make it work just use `ColorableNavigationController` instead of `UINavigationController` and adopt needed child view controllers to `NavigationBarColorable` protocol.

**Example:**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, NavigationBarColorable {
    public var navigationBarTintColor: UIColor? { return UIColor.blue }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Push", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.showController))
    }

    func showController() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB(), animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, NavigationBarColorable {
    public var navigationBarTintColor: UIColor? { return UIColor.red }
}

let navigationController = ColorableNavigationController(rootViewController: ViewControllerA())
```

Answer (score 20):

To achieve this kind of animation you should use `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` as [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator) say it is :

> An object that adopts the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator protocol provides support for animations associated with a view controller transition.(...)

So every `UIViewController` has own `transitionController`. To get this you should call in the `UIViewControllerClass` :

`self.transitionCoordinator()`

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619294-transitioncoordinator):

> Returns the active transition coordinator object.

So to get the result that you want you should implement `animateAlongsideTransition` method in viewController transitionCoordinatior. Animation works when you click `backButton` and swipe to back.

Example :

[image: navigation_bar_animation]

First Controller :

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "A"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "NEXT", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.showController))
        setColors()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    func showController() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerB(), animated: true)
    }

    private func animate() {
        guard let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator else {
            return
        }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            [weak self] context in
            self?.setColors()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setColors() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Second Controller:

```
class ViewControllerB : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        title = "B"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setColors()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) { // tricky part in iOS 10
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red //previous color
        super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

    private func animate() {
        guard let coordinator = self.transitionCoordinator else {
            return
        }
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {
            [weak self] context in
            self?.setColors()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setColors(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

}
```

***UPDATE iOS 10***

In the iOS 10 the tricky part is to add the `willMoveTo(parentViewController parent: UIViewController?)` in the ***second*** ViewController. And set the navigationBar `tintColor` to the color value of ***previous*** controller. Also, in `viewDidAppear` method in ***second*** ViewControler set the `navigationBar.tintColor` to the color from ***second*** viewController.

***Check out my example [project on github](https://github.com/k8mil/NavBarColorAnimation)***

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I receive the same results as in my question (swipe back is okay, tap back is blinking). Sample project from your code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42855950/NavigationTransition.zip

Comment: @Vasily I'll check it

Comment: okay, please check, if you find solution update answer or remove if that is incorrect solution

Comment: I'll let you know or remove it, Are you using swift 3 on Xcode8, right?

Comment: I spent some time on this, and my previous code works fine on iOS 9 and Swift 2.2. The problem appears on iOS 10. Check my updated code and the example github [project](https://github.com/k8mil/NavBarColorAnimation)

Comment: just created own solution based on some of your ideas, I think my solution will be easier to use in real application because it overrides push & pop methods and you don't need to remember previous colors in view controllers :).

Comment: Your solution is very nice! I've focused only on providing a working solution and finding a way to fix that tricky bug in iOS 10 and finally I did that. So it would be nice if you upvote my answer or even accept. :)

Comment: @kamwysoc from my testing, looks like `viewDidAppear` is not necessary for `ViewControllerB`.

Comment: @kamwysoc Thanks dude!! Your iOS 10 Update helped me! thanks for saving people's time :thumbsup:

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
 override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
      super.willMove(toParent: parent)
      navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = previous view controller's navigation bar color
 }
```

Comment: This solution helped

Answer (score 1):

I am just wondering. For the same purpose I use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. In `navigationController(_:willShow:)` I start the animation using `transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)`. It works great when pushing new controllers, however pop doesn't.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
  let dst = viewController as! ViewController
  guard animated else {
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = dst.navigationBarColor
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = dst.tintColor
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = dst.barStyle
    return
  }

  navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = dst.navigationBarColor
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = dst.tintColor
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = dst.barStyle
  }, completion: { context in
    if context.isCancelled {
      let source = context.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as! ViewController
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = source.navigationBarColor
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = source.tintColor
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = source.barStyle
    }
})
```

Do you see any reason why it should work with pushes but not pops?

[image: push and pop]

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm struggling with *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: Nope, I gave up the transition and use transparent navigation bar and then in controller I create a view which simulates the background...

Comment: I actually made it work a couple of hours after I commented here. It was not pretty, but it works. I am now struggling with animating the UIStatusBarStyle..

Comment: Did you make it work by overriding `willMove(toParentViewController:)` or differently?

Comment: Using `animateAlongside` in common superclass's willAppear. Everything worked, except popping the view with the regular back-button. Pushing worked, and swiping back worked. To fix it I subclasses navigationController, overrode `popViewController`, and set tintcolor etc there. The problem was that swiping back also triggers this function. However, navigationController has its own gestureRecognizer for the back-swipe. So before doing anything inside `popViewController` I check the state of that gesture. If the state is `possible`, then the user is not swiping back.