# How do I transition/animate color of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have been searching for how to transition/animate the `barTintColor` of a `UINavigationBar` for a while now, and I only see different answers. Some use `UIView.animateWithDuration`, some use `CATransition`, but the most interesting ones, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250912/1203228) use `animate(alongsideTransition animation..`, which I like the sound of, but I can't get it working properly. Am I doing something wrong?

Many specify that I can simply use the `transitionCoordinator` in `viewWillAppear:`. I have set up a fresh super tiny project like this:

```
class RootViewController:UIViewController{ //Only subclassed
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self](context) in
            self?.setNavigationColors()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    func setNavigationColors(){
        //Override in subclasses
    }
}

class FirstViewController: RootViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "First"
    }
    override func setNavigationColors(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    }
}
class SecondViewController: RootViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Second"
    }
    override func setNavigationColors(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    }
}
```

With this code, this happens:
[image: First]

- The push-transition from `First` to `Second` looks perfect. All elements transition perfectly, maybe except the StatusBar, which instantly changes to white. I'd rather know how to transition it, but I'll accept it for now.
- The pop-transition from `Second` to `First` is completely wrong. It keeps the colors from `Second` until the transition is completely done.
- The drag-transition from `Second` to `First` looks alright, when dragging all the way over. Again, the StatusBar instantly becomes black as soon as I start dragging, but I don't know if that's possible to fix.
- The drag-transition from `Second` to `First` but cancelled mid-drag and returning to `Second` is completely screwed up. It looks fine until `Second` is completely back in control, and then it suddenly changes itself to `First`-colors. This should not happen.

I made a few changes to my `RootViewController` to make it a little better. I removed `viewWillAppear:` completely, and changed it with this:

```
class RootViewController:UIViewController{

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        if let last = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as? RootViewController{
            if last == self && self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count > 1{
                if let parent = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2] as? RootViewController{
                    parent.setNavigationColors()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let parent = navigationController?.viewControllers.last as? RootViewController{
            parent.animateNavigationColors()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.setNavigationColors()
    }

    func animateNavigationColors(){
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self](context) in
            self?.setNavigationColors()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    func setNavigationColors(){
        //Override in subclasses
    }
}
```

With this updated code, I get this:
[image: Second]

A few observations:

- The transition from `First` to `Second` is the same
- The pop-transition from `Second` to `First` is now animating correctly, except from the back-arrow, the back-text (and the statusBar, but yeah..). These are instantly changed to black. In the first gif, you could see that the back-arrow and the back-text also transitioned.
- The drag-transition from `Second` to `First` also has this problem, the back-arrow and back-text are suddenly instantly black when starting. The barTint is fixed so that it doesn't get the wrong color when cancelling the drag.

What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to do this?

What I want is to transition all elements smoothly. The tint of the back-button, the back-text, the title, the barTint, and the statusBar. Is this not possible?

Comment: I've been searching for a solution to this for months.

Comment: @mxcl https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929155/1336510

Answer (score 11):

[image]

in 10 iOS it works imperfectly :(

Subclass your navigation controller to use statusbarstyle of visible view controller:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return visibleViewController!.preferredStatusBarStyle
    }
}
```

Override preferredStatusBarStyle in Root controller and add function to set styles *before* pop animation:

```
private var _preferredStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default;
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    get {
        return _preferredStyle
    }
    set {
        _preferredStyle = newValue
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

}


func animateNavigationColors(){
        self.setBeforePopNavigationColors()
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self](context) in
            self?.setNavigationColors()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

func setBeforePopNavigationColors() {
    //Override in subclasses
}
```

In first controller:

```
override func setBeforePopNavigationColors() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

override func setNavigationColors(){
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    self.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
}
```

In second:

```
  override func setNavigationColors(){
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        self.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }
```

Example project: https://github.com/josshad/TestNavBarTransition

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the other question/answer gets deleted in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the push and pop methods of `UINavigationController` to set the bar color. I've stored the bar color corresponding to a view controller in its navigation item with a custom subclass of `UINavigationItem`. The following code works for me in iOS 11 for full and for interactive transitions as well:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationItem: UINavigationItem {
    @IBInspectable public var barTintColor: UIColor?
}

class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func applyTint(_ navigationItem: UINavigationItem?) {
        if let item = navigationItem as? NavigationItem {
            self.navigationBar.barTintColor = item.barTintColor
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        applyTint(self.topViewController?.navigationItem)
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        applyTint(viewController.navigationItem)
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        let viewController = super.popViewController(animated: animated)

        applyTint(self.topViewController?.navigationItem)
        return viewController
    }

    override func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        let result = super.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

        applyTint(viewController.navigationItem)
        return result
    }

    override func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        let result = super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)

        applyTint(self.topViewController?.navigationItem)
        return result
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return (otherGestureRecognizer is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Note: The coordination of the color animation is done by the navigation controller

Comment: Does this handle the color of the title and status bar?

Comment: It worked for me for both, but you should try it yourself.

Comment: I've tested this and it doesn't seem to cover the case when you're using the interactive pop gesture to swipe back and then change your mind and cancel the gesture -- in that case it sets the tint colour of the view controller that would have been popped to had you not cancelled the gesture