# Swift Navigation Bar Color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to set the navigation bar color for just a **single** View Controller in the navigation hierarchy? Let the default navigation bar color be red and just the last view controller in the line should have a blue one. I've used these two lines to color the navigation bar of said view controller:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

But when going back (e.g. by pressing the back button) the navigation bar stays blue. Setting the color back to red using above code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Where did you add your code snippet (the view controller life cycle method)?

Comment: In viewWillAppear in both the root as well as in the child view controller

Comment: Are you also calling super.viewWillAppear?

Comment: @userx it won't be the reason of the issue.

Comment: Let me be sure that I got your issue, so when navigating to the last view controller (which should has a blue bar) it works, but back to the previous one will make its bar is also blue not red, so you want to let it be red again? is this the case?

Comment: Perfectly correct @AhmadF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navigationBar` is shared across all the view controllers that are in the same `UINavigationController` stack.

If you want to change it's look for a specific view controller, you'll have to set the new style when the view controller is shown and remove it when the view controller is dismissed. This could be done in the `viewWillAppear`/`viewWillDisappear` of your view controller for example.

Comment: That worked! But now the color transition when going back to the previous view controller is kind of laggy. Is there a workaround to have the color set before the previous view controller appears?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014716/how-do-i-transition-animate-color-of-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 3):

I could get the navigation bar to change colors coming from a ViewControllerB to ViewControllerA perfectly fine with your code. I am not sure what your initial problem was. Here is my code which worked:

ViewController A:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
        //self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }


}
```

ViewController B:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

It worked without an issue.