# UINavigationBar transition between color and transparent - bug [iOS 11]

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios11

I've discovered a weird behavior on iOS 11 when I push `UIViewController` and change the `UINavigationBar` color to transparent. Important thing is that I'm using `largeTitles`.

1. I want to change red color of the navigation bar to transparent and this works fine.
2. However, if I tap on backButton, disable transparent style and red color style again something bad happened. NavigationBar on the ViewController is not red but still transparent.
3. As @Menoor Ranpura suggest I add another line which sets also a `backgroundColor` of view in `UIViewController` - and this is fine workaround when you set the same color like on `UINavigationBar`. However, it's not the solution for the problem because the large part of the navigation bar is still transparent. You can see it when you set the different color for a background. For example, I set the yellow. You can see the example here:

[image]

## Question

How to properly change the navigation bar color **from transparent** to **red again**, when the `prefersLargeTitles` is set to `true`?

## Code

```
class ExampleTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseID")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.redNavigationBar()
        title = "Red NavBar"
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        navigationController?.navigationBar.redNavigationBar()
    }
}

 //Transparent Navigation bar controller
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Transparent NavBar"
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transparentNavigationBar()
    }

}
extension UINavigationBar {
    func redNavigationBar() {
        setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        shadowImage = nil


        prefersLargeTitles = true
        tintColor = .white
        largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        barTintColor = .red
    }

    func transparentNavigationBar() {
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

### Some tips that I've already tested:

- Everything works fine when `prefersLargeTitles` is set to `false`
- Everything works fine when `prefersLargeTitles` is set to `true`, but `navigationBar` changes are between non transparent colors. For example, if changing between green <-> yellow
- I don't want to set `backgroundColor` on view. It's not an solution but kind of a workaround for this.

Here you can see a screen from XCode:

[image]

Interesting fact is that, there is something called: `_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView` which is transparent. **How to access it?**

#### Related problems:

- [Make UINavigationBar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent)
- [UINavigationBar change colors on push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243112/uinavigationbar-change-colors-on-push/40250912)

**You can find example project here: https://github.com/kamwysoc/LargeTitlesNavigationBarTransition**

---

## UPDATE referring to @Menoor Ranpura answer

Code that @Menoor Ranpura suggest is a kind of a workaround. It's not a solution to set the same `backgroundColor` on `UIViewController` view like `UINavigationBar` has. However, I go a bit further and I change the color for a different than `UINavigationBar` controller has. And as you can see on above gif, when the `largeTitle` appears, the navigation bar becomes yellow - which means that is transparent - because we're able to see the yellow background of view.

Comment: Bug still appears in iOS 12. Have you submitted a radar?

Answer (score 1):

call **greenNavigationBar()** in **viewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    view.backgroundColor = .red // this is kind of a workaround, However if you set color which will be different that `UINavigationBar` color you see that `largeTitle` is transparent because it shows a `backgroundColor` of a ViewController view.
    navigationController?.navigationBar.greenNavigationBar()
    title = "Green Title"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showTransparentViewController))
}
```

Comment: Have you test it in my example project? Because it's not working.

Comment: Could you share whole code? or maybe could you do a pull request with your fix? I will check it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you access `_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView`. I think you should submit a radar if you haven't already because setting the background colour this private ivar is only a hack and the issue at large still exists.

Swift 3/4:

```
if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar,
    let titleView = navigationBar.subviews.first(where: {type(of: $0) == NSClassFromString("_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView")}) {

}
```

Objective-C:

```
__block UIView *titleView;

[navigationController.navigationBar.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    Class _UINavigationBarLargeTitleView = NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView");
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView]) {
        titleView = subview;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```